# error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create some sample kubernetes pod file.

```
cat << EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: nginx
spec:
containers:
- name: nginx
  image: nginx
EOF
```

But on executing this I am getting below error.

> error: error validating "pod.yaml": error validating data:
>   [ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "containers" in
>   io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod, ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "na me" in
>   io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn
>   validation off with --validate=false

Comment: If the exact format you have presented in the statement is true, then I have to say that the problem is in the format. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#pod-templates.

Comment: Thanks @ShudiptaSharma. Its the issue with format. After observing the error for sometime i came to know it is clearly displaying that which fields in pod are not in right space indentation. Oberservation helps :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact issue but it got resolved with proper space indentation

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: nginx
spec:
 containers:
   - name: nginx
     image: nginx
```

It worked for me now with proper spaces. Mybad

Comment: Both version are valid YAML documents. In your question `spec` is a key in the root level mapping of the YAML file and has the value null, similar `containers` is a key in that same mapping with as value a list with one entry. In your answer the the value for `spec` is a mapping which has a key `containers`. As Kubernetes doesn't know about a root level key `containers`, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

error: error validating "one.yml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

if you get this error simply add this "--validate=false" at end of your recent command